# How to use both USB Mic (in) and on-board sound (out)

Tags: raspbian, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I'm trying  to set up my RPi with on-board sound out and a USB mic in, but everything I've found only deals with both audio i/o on the same (external) sound card. What's happening in my situation is that regardless of the default sound card I set, either one of `aplay` or `arecord` will fail with an error message that looks like: `arecord: main:682: audio open error: No such file or directory` (replace `arecord` with `aplay` if the default card is set to usb mic).

I know you can add the device name when running the command (`arecord -Dhw:1,0 test.wav` works, but `arecord test.wav` doesn't), but I would like that to not happen because I'm using a bunch of pre-compiled libraries that seem to only consider the default devices

EDIT:

For example, I have the following scenario:

in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, commenting out `options snd-usb-audio index=-2` will allow `arecord` to work, but not `aplay`, and uncommenting the above line will allow `aplay` to work, but not `arecord`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

adding an 'asymmetrical' ALSA device worked:

change the contents of `/etc/asound.conf` and `~/.asoundrc` to the following:

```
pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "hw:0,0"
    capture.pcm "hw:1,1"
}
```

and `sudo alsa force-reload` for good measure

Comment: My journey started with `ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave` and after a few hours, I ended up here. Great fix, thx.