# Alsa setup for multiple cards

Tags: alsa

I have connected Logitech C310 webcam on USB port and my speaker audio jack to the on board audio jack on my Rpi2.

Now i want my alsa to use usb webcam to record audio and play the sound through speaker using the audio jack.

Cards:

```
$rpi2> cat /proc/asound/cards

     0 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835 - bcm2835 ALSA
                          bcm2835 ALSA
     1 [U0x46d0x81b    ]: USB-Audio - USB Device 0x46d:0x81b
                          USB Device 0x46d:0x81b at usb-3f980000.usb-1.3, high speed
```

Please help me to set this up.

Thanks/Tanvir

Comment: Duplicate of [How to use both USB Mic (in) and on-board sound (out)](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/43283/17471) and [How to configure and select USB Microphone](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/45500/17471).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have studied this [link](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc)  and found my solutions.

In my case the speaker directly connected to the Rpi and mic is connected through USB.

```
#cat /proc/asound/cards

 0 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835 - bcm2835 ALSA
                      bcm2835 ALSA
 1 [U0x46d0x81b    ]: USB-Audio - USB Device 0x46d:0x81b
                      USB Device 0x46d:0x81b at usb-3f980000.usb-1.3, high speed
```

**Solution:**

I have added bellow lines to my /etc/asound.conf

```
pcm.primary{
        type hw
        card 0
        device 0
}

pcm.secondary{
        type hw
        card 0
        device 1
}
```

Now i can record my voice using

```
arecord -d secondary rec1.wav
```

And Play using

```
aplay -D primary rec1.wav
```

As i understand this problem has many solutions and from them i choose my one which i feel easy for me.

Thanks all,

Tanvir